# Obtener valores e imprimirlos - Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean in

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy intentando obtener valores de una fila llamada `agent_id` en mi tabla `clients`. La tabla contiene valores repetidos y quiero saber el numero de repeticiones de cada valor. Los valores pueden ser entre 1 y 24, pero no necesariamente deben existir en la fila.

Por ejemplo: puede que no haya ningún registro con el numero 13, he utilizado `php` para que mi consulta cambie el valor en mi condición `where`

```
for ($i=1; $i<=24 ; $i++) { 
    $consulta='SELECT count(vehicle_id) from clients where vehicle_id=$i';
    $resultado = $con -> query($consulta);      
    while ($fila = $resultado -> fetch_array()) {
        echo $fila['vehicle_id]; echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

Utilizo el contador del `for` y se lo paso como variable de comparación en el `where` a la consulta. Después utilizando un ciclo `while` imprimo los resultados, pero obtengo el error mencionado en el titulo.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega un `if` dentro pones el `while`, porque precisamente te esta devolviendo un valor `booleano` que probablemente es un `false`. Osea cuando no hay consultas te regresa `false`.

```
for ($i=1; $i<=24 ; $i++) { 
  $consulta='SELECT count(vehicle_id) from clients where vehicle_id=$i';
  $resultado = $con -> query($consulta);
  if($resultado){
    while ($fila = $resultado -> fetch_array()) {
      echo $fila['vehicle_id]; echo "<br />";
    }
  }   
}
```

Comment: ¿Exactamente como lo agrego? verifico si resultado esta vacio?

Comment: edite el comentario, intenta asi,  deberia funcionar.

Comment: sino funciona eso intenta cambiar el if por if($resultado->num_rows !== 0), lo que pasa es que eso funcionaria en laravel pero no estoy seguro en php solo.